# limit slope of linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have a list of float number in python as follows: 1.2 2.1 3.0 5.4

I want to find the best line which fits on this set of points, with a constraint that the slope of the line should be less than a specific value.

Can someone please help me to find the best line?

Comment: You should add some code on what you have tried so far, so that others see that you have put some effort in to find a solution on your own.

Comment: You might have better luck on the Computer Science Stackexchange https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow a 2-step approach:

1. Calculate the linear regression like described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression or directly use `numpy.polyfit`(described here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)
2. Check the slope of the found line with your limit and chose the minimum of both.